# How to find least squares solution with multidimensional data?

Tags: regression, least-squares, supervised-learning, high-dimensional

I have a data set, on which I want to learn the matrices A and b. So my model is :

$$
Y = Ax + b
$$

and let's say $x$ is of size $11$x$1$, and $Y$ is $9$x$1$. And I have $50$ observations ($50$ pairs of $x$ and $Y$). I'm giving these numbers because I'm confused in understanding the dimensionality. So $A$ should be $9$x$11$, and $b$ should be $9$x$1$ (right?)

So, what I've done is :

I first re-wrote the equation :

$$
Y = [A, b] [x;1]
$$

So now my regression problem is 
$$
Y = Cz
$$

and $C (=[A,b])$ should be of dimension $9$ x $12$, and I need to "learn" $C$ from the observations. As far as I understood, linear least squares solution says

$$
C = (z'z)^{-1} z' Y
$$

but the dimension of $(z'z)$ is 1x1, so it's a scalar. I'm really confused here.

How can I compute the value of C in this example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are confusing two forms of notation: your model places the parameters $A$ to the left of the variables $x$, whereas you are quoting a solution where the matrix operations have been reversed.

Comment: Yes probably I'm confusing something. I'm also not sure if X is a single observation or the matrix of all observations. How do I compute these parameters?

Comment: It looks like a standard [multivariate regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=multivariate+regression) problem: follow the link for related posts on our site.